# Trying to check if a checkbox is checked, please, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{   
    $('input[id^="btnRemoveCategory"]').bind(
        'click',
        function(){
            if($('input[id^="chkIsBottom_":checked]'))
                alert('YES YES YES!!!!');
            else
                alert('No NO no!!!!!');
```

I've tried with the:

```
if($('input[id^="chkIsBottom_"]').attr(checked))
```

also....

where is my mistake???

10x

Comment: 10x...i went with door number 2...lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[id^="chkIsBottom_":checked]')
```

… is always going to return a true value. If none are checked, then it will be a jQuery object with no element inside it. You want:

```
$('input[id^="chkIsBottom_":checked]').length
```

(which will be false if the length is 0, and true if it isn't)

Meanwhile:

```
if($('input[id^="chkIsBottom_"]').attr(checked))
```

… will get the value of the X attribute of the **first** input element with an id that starts with chkIsBottom_, where X is whatever the variable *checked* contains (which is probably undefined, since you probably intended to pass a string).

Comment: 10x, this did the job perfectly and then for the explenation :-)
i will axcept it in 5 minutes, i can't right now....

Answer (score 2):

You were very close with your first implementation.

Try this adjustment:

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{   
    $('input[id^="btnRemoveCategory"]').bind(
        'click',
        function(){
            if($('input[id^="chkIsBottom_"]:checked').length > 0)
                alert('YES YES YES!!!!');
            else
                alert('No NO no!!!!!');
```

Another option:

```
if($('input[id^="chkIsBottom_"]').is(':checked'))
```

Comment: 10x, i went with the other one, but 10x :-)